# Python and "import requests" on HTTP Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, mailgun

I am trying to create a simple HTTP request to a Google Cloud function, so when I call the Google Cloud URL a mail will be sent via the Mailgun API.

Below is the very basic Mailgun code I used in PyCharm to test the connection and everything is working fine. When I run this function on my computer I'll receive an email in my inbox.

```py
import requests

def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mg.my.url.com/messages",
        auth=("api", "XXXXXxKEYxXXXXX"),
        data={"from": "Name <name@mg.my.url.com>",
              "to": "name@outlook.com",
              "subject": "Hello You",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})

send_simple_message()
```

As soon as I create an HTTP function in GCP and copy/paste the same code there I get an error. The only difference is I added `requests==2.21.0` to the `requirements.txt` file. I believe this tells Google Cloud to include the requests module in Python.

Error I'm getting from logfile:

> Error: function crashed. Details:
>   'Request' object has no attribute 'post'

Do I need to add another module to Python?

---

Added extra log information:
[image]

Comment: Are there any other messages in Stackdriver before this error? You either have a library version conflict or a library is missing. Note that the current version of requests is 2.22.0.

Comment: I've tried adding the most recent version of Requests but that didn't matter for the result. So I started my search in the Documentation of Cloud Functions and saw the older version being used there. That's why I tried that version.

Comment: The simplest way to fix this is to use virtualdev. Create a directory and then run `pip install -U requests`. `pip freeze` will show you the imports for requirements.txt. The Python module `requests` depends on other modules. In Cloud Functions, you need to specify everything and not assume that Cloud Functions will figure it out for you.

Comment: What do you want to return? Since when I'm trying to run your code I'm getting "Error: function crashed. Details:
'Response' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a Response."
Only way how I can reproduce your error is typo "request.post()"

Comment: Also you don't need to invoke "send_simple_message()" in the end, just write "send_simple_message" in "Function to execute" box.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have a paid Mailgun account I can't help you with detailed code but I would suggest you take a look at this function from the official [App Engine](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/6879d73123135459fa45a36211505d1ead37978a/appengine/flexible/mailgun/main_test.py) where using also responses lib they manage to use Mailgun. Cloud functions are based on App Engine so this must be close to what you want to achieve.

```
import os
import pytest
import requests
import responses

@pytest.fixture
def app(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('MAILGUN_DOMAIN_NAME', 'example.com')
    monkeypatch.setenv('MAILGUN_API_KEY', 'apikey')

    import main

    main.app.testing = True
    return main.app.test_client()


@responses.activate
def test_send_simple(app):
    responses.add(
        responses.POST,
        'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/example.com/messages',
        body='')

    response = app.post('/send/email', data={
        'recipient': 'user@example.com',
        'submit': 'Send simple email'})
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert len(responses.calls) == 1
```

Comment: The library `responses` is great, but this library is used to "mock" requests for testing and not for deployed code.

Comment: @Jack Ottermans, Can you please let us know if the above answer helped you ?

Answer (score -1):

You should write the import inside your function. Plus it's not necessary to instantiate the request, you should invoke it from the entry point.

Hope it helps,

```
def send_simple_message():
    import requests
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mg.my.url.com/messages",
        auth=("api", "XXXXXxKEYxXXXXX"),
        data={"from": "Name <name@mg.my.url.com>",
              "to": "name@outlook.com",
              "subject": "Hello You",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})

send_simple_message()
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help